# change cell in datagridview to empty value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have method to change cell in datagridView and works fine when i rewrite text (String) .
But I want for example rewrite email to empty value and I dont know how do this. 
I can only rewrite email to another email (string to another string)

My method to change cell is :

```
public void ChangeCellEmail(int col, string[] emails)
    {


        string sep = ";";
        string text = "";

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < emails.Length ;i++)
            {

                if (emails[i].ToString().Trim() != "")
                {


                    text = text + emails[i] + sep ;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[col].Value = text;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

The calling code of my method is

```
            string mail = txtBox1.Text;
            string mail1 = txtBox2.Text;
            string mail2 = txtBox3.Text;
            string mail3 = txtBox4.Text;
            string mail4 = txtBox5.Text;

            string[] mails = new string[] { mail, mail1, mail2, mail3, mail4 };


            frm1.ChangeCellEmail(2, mails);
            this.Dispose();
```

Thanks for help guys .

Comment: If I understand your question correctly and if both emails are string, then why not try use / set the email value to string.empty

Comment: it is not solution I want rewrite string to empty value ... for example I have the value of cell : a@g.com, I want edit this value to empty value so i delete a@g.com click save but still there is a@g.com .... for example when i want rewrite   a@g.com the same way like above it works fine

Comment: So does the database actually update though? i.e. if you change a@g.com to b@g.com does the database reflect this new change?
(Are you submitting the changes to the database?)

Comment: Yes i am submitting the changes to the database

Comment: So if you change this line `dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[col].Value = text;` to this `dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[col].Value = string.Empty;` and update the database, does it reflect the new change?

Comment: Yes when i rewrite email to another email the new change is empty value but when i rewrite email to empty vaule there is still email

Comment: `text = text + emails[i] + sep;` could be written as `text = string.Join(sep, emails.Where(e => e.ToString().Trim() != ""));` (outside of the loop). So, you're creating a semi-colon-separated list of email addresses, and assigning the result to the cell ... right?

Comment: Yes i create  a semi-colon-separated list of email addresses but this code text = string.Join(sep, emails);  doesnt work because i have array of many emails and when i drite for example one email the output is a@g.com;;;;;;; ...

Comment: @user2641465 have you tried declaring the `string text = "";` within the foreach loop?

Comment: yes i try it within the loop and also out of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following code I can pass in 5 complete email address's of which some / all could be "empty" and the `tempVar` will always contain the correct data.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        const string mail = "First";
        const string mail1 = "Second";
        const string mail2 = "Third";
        const string mail3 = "";
        const string mail4 = "Fifth";

        var mails = new string[] { mail, mail1, mail2, mail3, mail4 };

        ChangeCellEmail(2, mails);
    }


    public void ChangeCellEmail(int col, string[] emails)
    {
        var sep = ";";
        var text = "";
        var tempVar = ""; //New temp variable (representing your dataGrid.value)

        for (int emailList = 1; emailList < 5; emailList++)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < emails.Length; i++)
            {

                if (emails[i].Trim() != "")
                {
                    text = text + emails[i] + sep;
                    tempVar = text;
                }
                else
                {
                    tempVar = string.Empty;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Check the tempVar on each loop and you'll see what I am referring to.

Comment: i understand your solution but when i add                           else
                {
                    tempVar = string.Empty;
                }                                                    there will be still empty value

Comment: @user2641465 but thats what you've been saying you wanted? Quote: *But I want for example rewrite email to empty value and I dont know how do this*, so if you could explain how the above code doesnt complete your task, maybe we can help further?

Comment: i dont want rewrite default empty value

Comment: @user2641465 So, you would like to pass in 5 emails (for example) and if any of them are blank, you wish to ignore them. i.e. tempVar should only have *real* values?

Comment: i want pass 5 emails if any of them is blank, save to datagrid value empty value , if any of them is string save to datagrid string

Comment: @user2641465 But thats exactly what the above code does, if any of the email(s) within the array are blank, the tempVar will be set to "" / string.empty, else, the tempVar will = the *real* email address.
So, tempVar will either be string.Empty / "" or have real data - which you can use to update the database?
So, should you use `dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[col].Value = tempVar` then the database will either be updated with a blank string or a valid email string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggested solution:

```cs
public void ChangeCellEmail(int emailColumnIndex, string[] emails)
{
  var emailsAsCsv = string.Join(";", emails.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e)));
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
  {
    dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[emailColumnIndex].Value = emailsAsCsv;
  }
}
```

This updates the selected cells' `Email` column with the a semi-colon-separated list of non-empty emails.

Usage:

```cs
var emailColumnIndex = 2; // The third column in the DataGridView (zero-indexed)
var emails = new[] {txtBox1.Text, txtBox2.Text, txtBox3.Text, txtBox4.Text, txtBox5.Text};
ChangeCellEmail(emailColumnIndex, emails);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have array of emails not only  string emailValue

Comment: Why? Your question states that you want to set a column value to the empty string. What is the role of the array of emails? Do you use these to filter out the list of columns you want to set as empty string?

Comment: Because I can add more emails not just one ... but i want when i delete string email on the any position from array there will be empty string

Comment: @user2641465 Perhaps you should edit your initial question with the calling code that is used in conjunction with this method, ths way, maybe we could understand you query a little more?

Comment: @user2641465 So will adding an `Else` statement to your `If` statement help? i.e. 
`Else {dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[col].Value = string.Empty;}`

Comment: good idea with the if statement but not working when i enter email  there will be still empty value

Comment: So, you want to _replace_ the selected columns' values with a semi-colon-separated list of emails?

Comment: @user2641465 so am I correct in saying that one of these could be empty?
`string mail1 = txtBox2.Text;
string mail2 = txtBox3.Text` and thats what you want to cater for?

Comment: ano of these columns sholud  be empty ... the user can write email or rewrite it to another email or to empty value , my solution wokrs only for rewriting to another email

Comment: the output is  a@g.com;;;;  i also add there if condition to Text.Trim !=""  but stil  a@g.com;;;; , empty value works fine

Comment: @user2641465 I think the issue lies in your data access / databinding code, because my code above works just fine.

Comment: Then the string[] emails array is either empty or contains items that have empty string values ... put in some breakpoints and debug it.